# Tap Gesture Recognizer for View but not Sub-View in CustomView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have created a customViewController to act as a customActionsheet. In this customViewController I have a UIView as the main view (self.view) and an IBOutlet UIView that is the custom action sheet (actionSheetView). What I am trying to do is make this custom action sheet act like a regular actionsheet where if you tap in the dark area, in my case the view with blackColor background and alpha 5.0. This is what I have:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(slideOut)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

The problem with this is that the subview, the custom action sheet view, also gets the tapgesture so tapping anything on the actionSheetView will get the tap gesture. I have tried a few things like `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` and `self.actionSheetView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` but both do not seem to work. Anyone have any idea of how I can make the self.view tappable but disable that gesture for self.actionSheetView? Any tips, guidance, or help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before implementing the selector that you have mentioned did you actually set the subview to be a delegate of the gesture recgonizer? (`tapGesture.delegate = your_subview`)

Answer (score 3):

I was working on this same style of system.  I found it works if you:

1. Add a new UIView as a subview of the main UIView.
2. Create another UIView where you want the custom UI (could be a table like an action sheet, a picker, etc).  Make sure this shows above the UIView in step 1.
3. Register the UITapGestureRecognizer on the UIView from step 1.
4. (Optional) Add extra buttons (e.g. "Cancel" and "Done") and set up a delegate that your custom controller fires.

The main UIView (self.view) should be opague, clear color with alpha of 1.  The full subview (see step 1) can be any color (I used light gray color), but adjust the alpha value (0.5 for me).

Unfortunately I can't post an image because I don't have enough rep on the site yet.

If you're using IB and having trouble receiving taps, check under the Attributes Inspector (under the view section) to make sure that "User Interaction" is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate

```
tapGesture.delegate = self.actionSheetView


//actionSheetView.m
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
     return NO;
}
```

Comment: I get a Warning: `Assigning to 'id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'UIView'`

Comment: Make sure your custom actionSheetView declares that it uses the protocol `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`in actionSheetView.h (or whatever your header file is)

Comment: Adam I added <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> to the header file and thats the message I got.

Comment: 1) Make sure in your class that self.actionSheetView is assigned the proper type (right now you must have `@property ... UIView *actionSheetView`) - make sure it is `@property ... YourSubClass *actionSheetView`) OR 2) cast it like this: `tapGesture.delegate = (YourSubClass*)self.actionSheetView`

Comment: I casted it and got the error to go away. This doesn't work though. My main view, self.view, is not tapable.